# Creating access permissions with Pow Elixir phoenix

Tags: authorization, elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to create some access validations in my application.

And I need your help for that.

How do I get the standard user to access only their own records and not be able to change another user?

I have several tables, and everyone has user_id, profile_id, config_id, post_id, dash_id ....
All are filled, but I don't know how to compare the user_id of the user table with the table config_id, profile_id, post_id, dash_id

How do I do that?
I currently use
https://github.com/danschultzer/pow

I ended up opening a post on the elixir forum, but without success.
https://elixirforum.com/t/improving-access-permissions-pow-authentication/32486

Could help me create this plug?

Currently the only thing I have is

EnsureRolePlug

```
defmodule MyprojectWeb.EnsureRolePlug do
  @moduledoc """
  This plug ensures that a user has a particular role.

  ## Example

      plug MyprojectWeb.EnsureRolePlug, [:user, :admin]

      plug MyprojectWeb.EnsureRolePlug, :admin

      plug MyprojectWeb.EnsureRolePlug, ~w(user admin)a
  """
  import Plug.Conn, only: [halt: 1]

  alias MyprojectWeb.Router.Helpers, as: Routes
  alias Phoenix.Controller
  alias Plug.Conn
  alias Pow.Plug

  @doc false
  @spec init(any()) :: any()
  def init(config), do: config

  @doc false
  @spec call(Conn.t(), atom() | binary() | [atom()] | [binary()]) :: Conn.t()
  def call(conn, roles) do
    conn
    |> Plug.current_user()
    |> has_role?(roles)
    |> maybe_halt(conn)
  end

  defp has_role?(nil, _roles), do: false
  defp has_role?(user, roles) when is_list(roles), do: Enum.any?(roles, &has_role?(user, &1))
  defp has_role?(user, role) when is_atom(role), do: has_role?(user, Atom.to_string(role))
  defp has_role?(%{role: role}, role), do: true
  defp has_role?(_user, _role), do: false

  defp maybe_halt(true, conn), do: conn
  defp maybe_halt(_any, conn) do
    conn
    |> Controller.put_flash(:error, "Acesso não autorizado!")
    |> Controller.redirect(to: Routes.dashboard_path(conn, :index))
    |> halt()
  end
end
```

Comment: This may be useful - Authorization in Phoenix web applications using Role Based Access Control (RBAC): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TlcVk-1Tpc


  Or a different approach using Bodyguard hex package:
https://hexdocs.pm/bodyguard/readme.html#plugs

Comment: *Currently the only thing I have is* -- And yet, there is so much more to copy [here](https://github.com/danschultzer/pow/blob/master/guides/user_roles.md)